# Lebesgue differentiation theorem for Radon measures

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request

Given any Radon measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and locally integrable function $f$, the generalized version of the Lebesgue differentiation theorem states that $$ \lim_{r \downarrow 0} \frac{1}{\mu(B(x,r))} \int_{B(x,r)} f d \mu = f(x)  \; \; \; \; \mu-a.e   $$
where $B(x,r)$ is a Euclidean ball of radius $r$.

I'm looking for a reference that provides the same statement for balls constructed using other equivalent norms on $ \mathbb{R}^n$. In particular, when $B(x,r)$ is a ball of radius $r$ with respect to the $ \| . \|_{\infty}$ norm.

Edit : Please note that I am looking for a reference that states this for all radon measures.

Answer (score 0):

A more general statement of this result is given in Folland's Real Analysis (Theorem 3.21 on page 98). Specifically, consider a family of Borel sets $\{E_r\}_{r> 0}$ in  $\mathbb{R^n}$ that "shrink nicely" to $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, i.e.,

- $E_r\subset B(r,x)$ for each $r$, and
- $\exists\alpha >0$, independent of $r$, s.t. $\mu(E_r)>\alpha \mu(B(r,x))$. ($\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure here.)

The result is as follows:

> Suppose $f\in L^1_{loc}$. Then for almost every $x\in\mathbb{R^n}$,
> $$
> \lim_{r\to 0}\frac{1}{\mu(E_r)}\int_{E_r}f(y)\,d\mu(y)=f(x)
> $$
> for every family $\{E_r\}_{r>0}$ that shrinks nicely to $x$.

The same result holds for regular Borel measures (see, e.g., Theorem 8.4.6 [here](https://books.google.nl/books?id=o928IAmynmoC&dq=benedetto%20integration%20and%20modern%20analysis&source=gbs_book_other_versions)).

Comment: Rudin's RCA also has this result.

Comment: This statement is more general only for Lebesgue measure. In general, it is not true that $\mu(E_r) > \alpha \mu (B(r,x))$ for a general radon or probability measure $\mu$ (even when you construct $E_r$ using balls with $\| . \|_{\infty}$ norm). Nonetheless, the lebesgue differentiation theorem still holds for these measures. I am looking for a reference that states this.

Comment: @Exc: You can always guarantee that inequality by rescaling either the euclidean balls or the cubes (what it boils down to is that both the 2 and $\infty$ norm are equivalent) by a factor depending only on dimension. This has nothing to do with a given measure, it's a purely geometric statement.

Comment: @Jose27 perhaps I'm missing something but what guarantees that you can rescale to satisfy this uniformly over the radius r for a general radon measure ? In particular, what if alpha tends to 0 as r goes to 0?

Comment: @Exc: Nevermind, for some reason I misread Folland's conditions. You're right that this (as in my argument) may fail for general Radon measures.